# jQuery works in a test fiddle but not in website

Tags: jquery, html, joomla

I have this short piece of code that copies content from one div into another on the click of a button:

```
<a id="btn123">CLICK ME</a>
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2">
<h1>Heading</h1>
</div>

$("#btn1").click(function(){
     $('#test1').html($('#test2').contents());
});
```

This works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/9hnZx/ but when i put it into my website it will not function, anyone know why? Thanks

http://bettondesignwork.co.uk/tim/j3mobile/

Comment: Do you add jquery.js to index.php of your website?

Comment: Please include all the code required to solve the problem *in your question*. You've modified that link in real time, in response to the answers below, and now this question is useless and broken. Your question cannot depend on external links to be answerable. This is not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: sorry this is gettin down voted, if i knew how to solve it i wouldnt have asked the question.... @mr.soroush it is included using the new JHtml::_('jquery.framework'); in Joomla3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` is no longer aliased to the jQuery object.

You're explicitly including "jquery-noconflict.js", the only contents of which is `jQuery.noConflict();`. The explicit intention of this line is to to *unalias `$` from jQuery*.

The following works:

```
jQuery("#btn1").click(function(){
     $jQuery('#test1').html(jQuery('#test2').contents());
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to do two things

1. include jQuery library
2. use document.ready.

Comment: Looks like he does include jQuery. http://bettondesignwork.co.uk/tim/j3mobile/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js

Comment: jQuery is included, and document.ready doesnt work, had it in but took it out and forgot to put it back, its there now but problem remains.

Comment: I could not see the script method in the source of page you gave in question, i.e. http://bettondesignwork.co.uk/tim/j3mobile/

Answer (score 0):

In joomla, there is a conflict between jquery and motools.
test it:

```
var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery("#btn1").on('click', function(){
      jQuery('#test1').html(jQuery('#test2').contents());
});
```

Comment: i have sinced disabled mootools and stop jQuery.noConflict.js from loading yet the problem remains, thanks anyway, ill keep fiddling!